# What happen if a WebSphere MQ FTE Agent is transfering files and another transference is activated

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

Hello i am new to IBM WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition and i have this question:

First i need to explain the situation: I have an Agent declared and i want to create a Transfer to run every minute in a folder, and it will delete the source file.

I want to know what happen when a transference is running and another minute pass. Will the Agent start a new Transference? If it creates a new , will it try to send again the files that are in the first Transference if they are still in the folder? or the Agent is going to wait until it finish the first transference and start the new one?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[
UPDATED/CORRECTION:
- Previously I stated that a scheduled transfer will not wait before starting a new instance, however this is incorrect. Testing I have performed has shown that a scheduled transfer will indeed not start a new instance of the transfer if a previously instance has not completed. Sorry for any confusion!
]

If you are using a "scheduled transfer":

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/create_schedule.htm

then the scheduled transfer will **not** start a new instance if a previous instance (transfer started by the scheduler) is already running. In this case, the WebSphere MQ FTE agent will instead publish a "**skipped**" audit message to the SYSTEM.FTE/LOG/ topic with the supplement:

**A previous instance of a repeating scheduled transfer (id:###...) is still running.**

However, I suggest you also look at Resource Monitoring as an alternative approach to scheduled transfers as it is a much more powerful feature.

Read the following section of the WebSphere MQ FTE Infocenter about the topic and it should give you plenty of information to get going and try it out yourself:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/resource_monitoring.htm

I hope this helps you!

Comment: The solution using resource monitoring really helped me, but i got another problem: The directory where the files are is dynamic, the files change anytime.
So i used this solution and also make the program that put the files in the folder wait until the trigger file is deleted to put more files in the folder.